# quickly create a cell array with two elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Given two matrices of distinct sizes, say matrices A and B, how to quickly create a cell array to store them? I know how to do this using the standard way as the following.

```
c = cell(1,2);
c{1}=A,
c{2}=B;
```

Is there a better way? Basically, what I am asking is to initialize a given cell array quickly in matlab. Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily write the statement in one line with **`C = {A,B}`**. This creates a cell-array with two columns and one row.

Let's test it with random data:

```
A = rand(2,2);
B = rand(3,3);
C = {A,B}
```

*This is the result:*

```
C = 
    [2x2 double]    [3x3 double]
```

---

In case you need two rows instead of two columns, just change the `,` to `;` like you would do to create a 'normal' matrix.

```
A = rand(2,2);
B = rand(3,3);
C = {A;B}
```

*This is the result:*

```
C = 
    [2x2 double]
    [3x3 double]
```

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise you can directly do

```
C = {A,B};
```